# How to extract a string in python using regex?

Tags: python, regex

Here is my example.

aStr = '[12345]dullboy'

I want to use regex to extract 'dullboy' from aStr. How to achieve that? Thanks.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to help without more detail of the pattern you want to match, but this should match anything after the closing square bracket:

```
import re
aStr = '[12345]dullboy'
m = re.search(r"\](.*)", aStr)
print(m.groups()[0])
```